# rsync removing in between directories

Tags: rsync

I am trying to create an rsync command that excludes a directory without effecting its contents, effectively moving them up 1 directory. In the below example I would want to exclude directories A & B recursively, C directory would be also be excluded however its contents would move into the above directory. is this possible with rsync?

SOURCE

```
/ORIGINAL
├── 1
│   ├── A
│   ├── B
│   └── C
│       ├── i
│       ├── ii
│       └── iii
├── 2
│   ├── A
│   ├── B
│   └── C
│       ├── i
│       ├── ii
│       └── iii
└── 3
    ├── A
    ├── B
    └── C
        ├── i
        ├── ii
        └── iii
```

DESTINATION

```
/BACKUP
├── 1
│   ├── i
│   ├── ii
│   └── iii
├── 2
│   ├── i
│   ├── ii
│   └── iii
└── 3
    ├── i
    ├── ii
    └── iii
```

The command below is what I hoped would work, however I think my include step is not right or the wrong function to achieve what i'm trying to achieve. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
rsync  -avhW --progress --delete \
--include C/ \
--exclude A \
--exclude B \
--exclude C \ 
"/Users/harry/Desktop/ORIGINAL/" \ 
"/Users/harry/Desktop/BACKUP"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly with `rsync`, so you'd need some supporting glue. By the time you'd worked out the best way to write that you might as well avoid `rsync` and do it differently.

I'm going to assume that although you appear to be using a Windows filesystem you have access to a UNIX/Linux-style shell and associated utilities.

```
base='/Users/harry/Desktop'

for src in "$base/ORIGINAL"/*/C/     # All C directories under …/ORIGINAL
do
    src="${src%/C/}"                 # Strip trailing /C/
    dst="$base/BACKUP/${src##*/}"    # Derive the corresponding destination
    mkdir -p "$dst"                  # Create destination directory if necessary
    cp -Rp "$src/C"/* "$dst/"        # Copy source files
done
```

Prefix both `mkdir` and `cp` with `echo` if you want to see what's going on without any action occurring. Taking this approach, here's the potential run with `base=/tmp`:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/BACKUP/1
cp -Rp /tmp/ORIGINAL/1/C/i /tmp/ORIGINAL/1/C/ii /tmp/ORIGINAL/1/C/iii /tmp/BACKUP/1/
mkdir -p /tmp/BACKUP/2
cp -Rp /tmp/ORIGINAL/2/C/i /tmp/ORIGINAL/2/C/ii /tmp/ORIGINAL/2/C/iii /tmp/BACKUP/2/
mkdir -p /tmp/BACKUP/3
cp -Rp /tmp/ORIGINAL/3/C/i /tmp/ORIGINAL/3/C/ii /tmp/ORIGINAL/3/C/iii /tmp/BACKUP/3/
```